# Monotouch - add files to your bundle with a build action

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, xamarin.ios

I would like to add DLL files to my application bundle but with a build action. Is it possible? If so could you give me an example how can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: I'm using several DLLs in my project that created from Library Projects. Right now every time I rebuild a library project I have to add it's DLL again by hand to my project. That's what I want to skip and add it automatically when I start my project.

Comment: This doesn't sound right: if you have a reference to a dll (or library project) in your main project, you shouldn't have to copy the dlls around manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your library projects to your main app's solution, so that when you build your app the libraries will also get rebuilt as necessary.

Alternatively, you could use a post-build action in your library project to copy the library dlls to another folder (a library folder, or the project folder for your app) where you app could then reference them.